# How to config NGINX for FLV streaming with proxy_cache?

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache, streaming, video

I have a media storage server with over 20GB of free RAM. Server stores a FLV files. I'm using NGINX with HttpFlvStreamModule for streaming. It works like a harm.
I thought to take advantage of free memory for storing the most popular movies. This will give a breath for hard drives. I've try to use proxy_cache with directory mounted to RAM. Proxy cache worked fine, but flv module stoped working and I couldn't rewind the movie (seeking).
I've tried several nginx configurations but none of them work as I want.

Also I`ve try to use proxy_store but it's pretty poor in cache options.
The proxy_cache_min_uses option is very important for selection of the most popular files.

Anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am misunderstanding your setup, you should *not* be using proxy_cache to speed things up, as nginx is on the same box as the media files. Just let the operating system use the extra RAM as filesystem cache (monitor and tune that behavior if necessary) - this will speed things up far more than proxy_cache would since everything is on the same box.

Nginx's proxy_cache (or Varnish, Squid, or any other HTTP cache) is only useful when the content you want to cache is on a *different* machine, or is being generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a discussion about that on the Nginx list. Apparently there's not much of a solution. Someone proposed using [this module](http://mdounin.ru/hg/ngx_http_bytes_filter_module/file/57365655ee44/README) as a replacement to `flv`, but no reports about it working or not.

Comment: I read this discussion and all other on web but nothing solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty much the only info about the problem.